# Cannot set depth buffer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In [some cocos2d-iphone documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aeffects), I was told to put this

```
// IMPORTANT: Call this function at the very beginning, before running your 1st scene
// Create a depth buffer of 24 bits
// These means that openGL z-order will be taken into account
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDepthBufferFormat:kDepthBuffer16];
```

To allow some 3D effects in my game with actions. However, for some reason, neither `setDepthBufferFormat` nor `kDepthBuffer16` are recognized by XCode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cocos2d documentation is partially out of date, unfortunately. The method you mentioned no longer exists. Instead, you will have to modify the line in the app delegate method applicationDidFinishLaunching that initializes the EAGLView. There's a "viewWithFrame" variant that takes the extra parameters of depthFormat:

```
// Create an EAGLView with a RGB8 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 24-bits
EAGLView* glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                               depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. By the way, do you know why when I run a 3d action, the background turns black?

Comment: Might be because of the missing depth buffer. You may also have to enable depth testing: [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDepthTest:YES];